# Running the Rinkeby network using geth on Windows

Tags: go-ethereum

I am [following these instructions here](https://gist.github.com/cryptogoth/10a98e8078cfd69f7ca892ddbdcf26bc) to setup `Geth` on a Windows 10 system for running on the Rinkeby network.

In Step 3, there are two lines of code to run

```
geth --datadir=$HOME/.rinkeby init rinkeby.json
geth --networkid=4 --datadir=$HOME/.rinkeby --cache=512 --ethstats="yournode:Respect my authoritah!@stats.rinkeby.io" --bootnodes=enode://a24ac7c5484ef4ed0c5eb2d36620ba4e4aa13b8c84684e1b4aab0cebea2ae45cb4d375b77eab56516d34bfbd3c1a833fc51296ff084b770b94fb9028c4d25ccf@52.169.42.101:30303 --rpc --rpcapi="personal,eth,network"
```

I ran the first line and it seems to be downloading the chain. What does the second line of code do? Do I run both lines at the same time??

Comment: New versions of geth (at least since v1.6.7) have the `--rinkeby` flag. So you only need to call `geth --rinkeby <other_parameters>  console`

Comment: @Ismael Something like `geth --rinkeby  --rpc --rpcapi="personal,eth,network,net,web3" --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1`? I am trying to use `truffle` to deploy a contract using `geth`

Comment: Indeed that line works to launch rinkeby testnet.

Answer (score 1):

They are consecutive lines. The first essentially initializes the Rinkeby chain by downloading the parameter from the genesis file. The second actually starts the download of the chain.

Comment: After running the second line, how can you tell that the chain download is happening? The last line I see is `INFO [09-18|11:56:25] HTTP endpoint opened: http://127.0.0.1:8545`, then after some time `INFO [09-18|11:58:58] Deduplicating database entries           deduped=100000`

Comment: I have never seen the deduplicating database line, so can't help you there. It will be obvious when the chain download will start, as you will see plenty of log entries with the block number you are at, the number of blocks downloaded etc. If that doesn't happen make sure that you are not behind a firewall; you can also get more information by adding `--verbosity=5` to the command line string, but be aware that it will generate lots of additional messages.